# Creating a composite foreign key for different tables using id and ENUM

Tags: postgresql, database-design, foreign-keys, data-integrity

I'm designing a PostgreSQL database schema where I need to establish a composite foreign key that references various tables based on an `ENUM` value stored in another column. In `main_table` has columns `target_id` and `target_type`. `target_type` column holds values from an `ENUM` type (`'TYPE_A'`, `'TYPE_B'` and `'TYPE_C'`).

My objective is to create a composite foreign key that links to distinct tables (`table_a`, `table_b` and `table_c`) based on `target_type`. For instance, when `target_type` is `'TYPE_A'` I aim for `target_id` to function as a foreign key pointing to `id` column in `table_a`. Something like this (but this example doesn't work):

```sql
ALTER TABLE main_table
    ADD CONSTRAINT fk_main_table_target_a 
        FOREIGN KEY (target_id, target_type)
            REFERENCES table_a (id, 'TYPE_A');
```

How to implement this dynamic foreign key setup using PostgreSQL? Could someone provide me with a detailed example of creating such a composite foreign key, ideally with an ENUM value-based selection?

Answer (score 1):

How to *implement this dynamic foreign key setup using PostgreSQL*. If by dynamic foreign key you mean defining a single column that can become an FK to different tables well **that cannot be done**. A FK column must always refer to the same table. You resolve this by creating a column for each table then validating only one of them is populated. Further this supersedes the need for a composite foreign key.

```
create type t_enum as enum('TYPE_A','TYPE_B','TYPE_C');
 
create table main_table 
           ( main_id       integer  generated always as identity
                                    primary key 
           , target_type   t_enum
           , type_a_id     integer  references table_a(id) 
           , type_b_id     integer  references table_b(id)
           , type_c_id     integer  references table_c(id) 
           -- other attributes ...
           , constraint just_one_abc CHECK (num_nonnulls(type_a_id,type_b_id,type_b_id) = 1)
           );
```

If you need to validate type vs. the referenced table then add a second constraint:

```
alter table main_table 
         add constraint match_one_abc CHECK (    (target_type = 'TYPE_A'::t_enum and type_a_id is not null)
                                              or (target_type = 'TYPE_B'::t_enum and type_b_id is not null)
                                              or (target_type = 'TYPE_C'::t_enum and type_C_id is not null)
                                            );
```

Comment: Now I have something like this table structure and the main drawback is that when adding a new type, I will have to add a new column.

Comment: Yes you will. Another approach would be combine them into a single type table. If the attributes are the same or close then this is a viable option. If there is an access issue then look into [Row Level Security](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-rowsecurity.html). Without knowing details one cannot suggest which is better.